# MAPI working locally but not on production computer

Tags: authentication, mapi

I just can't get MAPI to work on our production machines. I've already created an application that uses MAPI and sites on that very machine but for some reason I can get my new app to work. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Locally I've created an application that uses MAPI to log into a mail profile and retrieve messages. The messages are parsed and moved to 2 different folders one for errors and one for competed message. This all works perfectly on my computer but fails to login in production.

I know This is not a permissions issue because I'm using the same profile/pwd that my previous application is using. I thinking it may have something to do with the version of CDO or MAPI on my computer compared to the one in production but I'm just not sure.

Does anybody have any ensign into what CDO/MAPI versions I should be using, if some version don't work with different versions of windows...etc?

Answer (score 1):

Solved my own problem. Basically using MAPI in a MTA(Multi-Threaded Apartment) is bad news and should be avoided as much as possible. The problem I was having was do to running my MAPI code inside a MTA thread.